Spring Boot Not Loading Variables from .env Using java-dotenv
I'm trying to load environment variables from a .env file in my Spring Boot app using:
implementation 'io.github.cdimascio:java-dotenv:5.2.2'   

Here’s part of my application.properties:
spring.datasource.url=${DB_URL} spring.datasource.username=postgres spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD} stripe.api.key=${STRIPE_API_KEY}

My .env file:
DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb DB_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword STRIPE_API_KEY=my_stripe_key

The environment variables are not being loaded into application.properties when I run the app, and I get errors like:
URL must start with 'jdbc'

I tried  putting .env file is in the root directory and the Dotenv class reads the variables correctly in the main method.
How can I properly load the .env variables into Spring Boot’s application.properties using java-dotenv?
I wanted the .env to work and connect but it wont.

You should try to look at https://github.com/paulschwarz/spring-dotenv spring-dotenv project which injects .env file as spring-property-source
See another question like yours : Using dotenv files with Spring Boot
